# How can I track and sync Chrome Extension installs and interactions with website interactions using Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I would like to use Google Analytics to get a full understanding of my browser extension install and download process. From when the user lands on my website, tracking the events/pages they go through until they click a call to action to download and get taken to the chrome web store. Whether they download the extension after seeing the pages on the web store item. And finally some basic interactions with the extension itself and if/when they uninstall it.

The requirements would be to see a continuous flow of pages/events for a single user. So the analytics code must know that the user is the same from the website -> chrome store -> extension.

The Chrome store is unique in that it allows you to add a Google Analytics tracking code, which sends page views for an impression and an install. BUT looking at the current analytics it seems it is tracked as a separate user/session so the web store impression does not show up in in a Behavior Flow as a step after the user interacts with a link to the chrome web store.

I am open to using a different analytics platform, writing custom logic to pass `clientId` around, etc; especially if it can work seamlessly with other browser extension platforms (i.e. tracking Edge/Opera users). Major bonus points if the scheme can support tracking installs for Safari App Extension downloads through the app store.

Comment: have you found anything?

Comment: @WaqasMehmood long story short I manually set the analytics cookie value on the site and pass that value to the extension for storage during an initial set up request. I then load cookie value in the extension when setting up GA. I can write a more thorough response as an answer if you have additional questions.

Comment: @tomjohn can you provide more details about your solution, especially what do you mean by "setting up GA"?